# How to upload youtube videos with side channels using youtube api - C #

Tags: c#, winforms, api, youtube, youtube-api

I'm using YouTube's API to upload videos. However, my YouTube account has two channels, and I'm only able to successfully upload to the main channel, not the second channel.

Can anyone tell me what I need to do to upload to the second channel?

[image]

### The Code:

```
    private async Task Run(String title,String mota,String[] tag,String filepath)
    {
        UserCredential credential;

        using (var stream = new FileStream("client_secrets.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,                 
                new[] { YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubeUpload},
                "user",
                CancellationToken.None
            );
        }

        var youtubeService = new YouTubeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {

            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name
        });


        var video = new Google.Apis.YouTube.v3.Data.Video();

        video.Snippet = new VideoSnippet();
        video.Snippet.Title = title;
        video.Snippet.Description = mota;
        video.Snippet.Tags = tag;

        video.Snippet.CategoryId = "22"; 
        video.Status = new VideoStatus();
        video.Status.PrivacyStatus = "unlisted";

        var filePath = filepath;
        using (var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open))
        {
            var videosInsertRequest = youtubeService.Videos.Insert(video, "snippet,status", fileStream, "video/*");
            videosInsertRequest.ProgressChanged += videosInsertRequest_ProgressChanged;
            videosInsertRequest.ResponseReceived += videosInsertRequest_ResponseReceived;
            await videosInsertRequest.UploadAsync();
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is too general. Please edit to show us what you have tried so far and/ or ask some specific questions.

Answer (score 0):

You must authorize the correct account in the OAuth flow.  If the second account circled in red is a CMS account you must use the `onBehalfOfContentOwner` parameter in your API call.  Some calls also have the `forUsername` parameter which allow you to call on behalf of users, by supplying their username.

For example the [channels.list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list) mehtod has both a `onBehalfOfContentOwner` parameter and`forUsername` parameter.

Comment: You can edit your code is not helping, thank you so much :)